# Help with OOP for custom menu structure module

Tags: 8

I've created an html/css/js component for an accessible dropdown menu. Now that I'm using it in a few different places, and one of those places needs to generate the links programmatically, I'd like to package it as a module. I have a general understanding of OOP, but I just don't really understand the kinds of files that I need for this or the src folders that they should go in.

The structure of the menu itself is essentially (plus some attributes that I know got lost in editing:

```
<nav id="menuIdNav" class="c-accessibleDropdownMenu">
  <button id="menuIdTrigger" class="c-accessibleDropdownMenu__trigger" aria-controls="menuId" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" data-state="closed">
    <span id="menuIdTriggerLabel" class="c-accessibleDropdownMenu__triggerLabel">Menu Trigger Button Text</span>
    <span class="c-accessibleDropdownMenu__toggleArrow" aria-hidden="true" data-state="closed">▼</span>
  </button>
  <div id="menuId" class="c-accessibleDropdownMenu__target" data-state="closed" style="">
    <h1 id="menuIdLabel" class="c-accessibleDropdownMenu__heading">Menu Heading</h1>
    <ul>
      <li class="menu-item">
        <a href="/link1">Link1 Text</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item">
        <a href="/link2">Link2 Text</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

One variant uses multiple `<ul>` elements with their own `<h2>` headings to further categorize the menu items. In most of my use cases, these menus are generated on the fly so I don't need to leverage Drupal menus (although that would be great to support at some point).

I'm fairly certain that the class(es?) I use to generate the markup shouldn't be a:

- Controller, since they don't relate to a route
- Block plugin, since the object itself should be able to be rendered wherever it is needed, possibly within blocks provided by other modules.
- Entity or Form, because it is neither

Past that I'm just a bit lost on what my options are. I also see that Core has some classes just sitting right in /Core/lib -- is it a viable option to drop my class file directly into my module's `src` folder and call it a day or should it really be further classified/categorized.

Comment: It's a programmatically created block. With a block settings form. Where you define form elements to pass values to your block's `build()` function to dynamically build its output from. `mymodule/src/Plugin/Block/MyDynamicBlock.php`.

Comment: @laymannx why would it be a block if I want the class to be used in multiple places? There'd be one block using this class to create one menu, and other blocks doing the same with their own menus.

Comment: Imagine you provide a select settings element in that block which allows you to pass in a Drupal menu. Every instance of this block has its own settings values. Inside the block class you still can provide `public static function HelperFuntion()` to be used in multiple places and then create a service that calls that helper function.

Comment: Pretty similar to https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block I think.

Comment: Reusable, non-plugin based, functionality should be wrapped up in a service and injected into the various places it needs to be used. As far as markup goes, classes don't generate it, ideally - templates do. You already have `hook_theme()` if all you need is to generate markup, don't overthink it :)

Comment: @Clive thank you, service is exactly what I was looking for! And yes, I see that I'd want to leverage `hook_theme()` for the markup itself.